# Nearest inside Minimize

Tags: function-construction, mathematical-optimization, nearest

How to use `Nearest` inside `Minimize`?

The following returns errors but if `# - {a, b}` is replaced with `# - {1, 2}` it works correctly so I guess the errors are due to `Nearest` not returning numeric outputs.

```
x = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {10, 2}]
y = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {10, 2}]
Minimize[(# - Nearest[y, #][[1]] & /@ (# - {a, b} & /@ x))^2 // 
   Flatten // Total, {a, b}]
Clear[x, y]
```

Comment: I recommend using `nf = Nearest[...data...]` outside the `Minimize` first, then using the `nf` inside the minimize for performance reasons, to avoid repeatedly calculating the acceleration structure while doing the minimization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Use the `?NumericQ` skill.

```
SeedRandom[1];
x = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {10, 2}];
y = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {10, 2}]; 
f[a_?NumericQ, 
  b_?NumericQ] := (# - Nearest[y, #][[1]] & /@ (# - {a, b} & /@ 
        x))^2 // Flatten // Total;
 NMinimize[f[a, b], {a, b}]
```

> `{83.7, {a -> 0.3, b -> -0.8}}`